# API REST Full Attask client.Search(ObjCode.HOUR

Tags: attask

I'm unable to find the hours recorded on a particular date. I use the call below:

```
JToken Horas = 
client.Search(ObjCode.HOUR,new {isActive=true, Fields="entryDate > 2016-01-01"});
```

and always returns an error as bad request.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is the message of the response you are getting. Also what is the API call this is creating. The specific code you provided does not make the call clear you are making.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the modifiers listed in the website: `developers.workfront.com/api-docs/#Search`

Your call should look like this:

```
JToken Horas = client.Search(ObjCode.Hour, new { isActive=true, entryDate=2016-01-01, entryDate_Mod=gte});
```

Hope this helps.